# Apache Spark Streaming K-means: I need know how many iterations runs in the same data?

Tags: java, apache-spark, k-means

I'm newbie with **Spark**. I'm trying to read the code and to understand how **K-means in Spark Streaming** works. I do not know how can to get **the number of iterations** that the algorithm performs in the same data's group. I can't find the Java file with this information.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you

**Solution**: In this file /spark-1.5.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala there is a `while` statement in the `run` method that use a variable called `iteration` and Spark writes it in a log for each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a small addition to majitux' solution (I am not allowed to comment yet). If you want to know the number of iterations K-Means takes simply change the log level of SPARK to INFO. Either inside the shell using:

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
```

Or by setting it as default inside the *conf/log4j.properties*.

After K-Means finished running the string "KMeans++ converged in X iterations" will appear in the log.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize KMeans class, you can specify max-iteration parameters.

new KMeans().setMaxIterations(iterations)

then it will use that parameter for each prediction

Comment: Yes, I know. But sometimes algorithm performs fewer iterations than the maximum, so I need to know that number.

Comment: **I found the answer!**:  In this file /spark-1.5.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala there is a _while_ in  the **run** method that use a variable called **iteration** and Spark writes it in a log for each run.